# Titanium - ACS groupby query operator

Tags: cloud, titanium-mobile

Does anyone know if Appcelerator Cloud Services (ACS) supports "group by" operations? If so, can you provide an example. Can't find anything in the doc, but the doc often has stale info. I would think that it's a common query operation.

Or if it does not, maybe someone has a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to find answer for this? I am also stuck with this. Right now I have to query all the object paginate them and then do the group by in the code logic.

Let me know if you found any better answer on this

Comment: When I last checked, ACS does NOT support group-by operations. Whether it ever will is anyone's guess.